# Google App Maker navigate to page while getting page name from data model

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I've created a list of menu items with dynamic names from DataSource, I want to navigate to appropriate pages by clicking the menu items.
I have got this code where we can hard code the page name to use in `onClick` for the current menu item.

```
app.showPage(app.pages.home);
```

I want to use dynamic page name from DataSource for the current item in the list.

I've data model named `MenuItems` with 2 string fields `DisplayName` and `PageName`

*I want to use  `PageName` value in `showPage` method instead of hardcoded value--- Thanks for help*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should be able to change your code as follows:

```
app.showPage(app.pages[app.datasources.MenuItems.item.PageName]);
```

This will only work if your MenuItems datasource is loaded to the client however.

Let me add that if you are running this code out of a list widget and your onclick event of the list row is your navigation, then you can simplify your code by just doing:

```
app.showPage(app.pages[widget.datasource.item.PageName]);
```

This way you will eliminate the possibility of a race condition where App Maker may first recognize the the showPage() function before it will recognize the correctly selected item in your list widget.

Comment: Currently it's giving me this error, (I tried both ways):
(TypeError) : Cannot read property '__gwt_instance' of undefined
at SubMenuOffice.List1.List1Row.Link1.onClick:1:5

Comment: I'm using the link inside list item which is unnecessary I think,

Comment: @NadeemGorsi See my edits to the answer and let me know if it is still giving you the error? Also, how are you populating the datasource MenuItems? When doing something like using `app.pages._values` then you will only get the actual pages in your application, however if you use `Object.keys(app.pages)` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(app.pages)` then this will generate a property for '__gwt_instance'.

Comment: @NadeemGorsi Have you considered instead of using a separate dedicated datasource for MenuItems to just use `@pages._values` under the advanced datasource binding option?

Comment: I wanted selective pages for this menu,

Comment: @NadeemGorsi I just tried the same thing in my own application and it worked just fine. The only thing I can think of that would create an undefined error is if the PageName was not correctly entered into the datasource, in which case `app.pages[widget.datasource.item.PageName]` would in fact return undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200034/discussion-between-nadeem-gorsi-and-markus-malessa).

Comment: Yes, there was a capitalization problem. It's solved, Many thanks @Markus